# Is it appropriate to use bootstrap method to calculate confidence interval for risk difference?

Tags: chi-squared-test, bootstrap

I am performing a systematic review and while abstracting the data from one particular study I felt puzzled by the way its authors tested the null hypothesis of no difference between the exposed and unexposed groups in a prospective cohort study.

Here are the data:

```
Number of diseased in the exposed group: 135
Total population in the exposed group: 52591

Number of diseased in the non-exposed group: 77
Total population in the non-exposed group: 64429
```

Instead of using usual Chi-square to compare the cumulative incidences and to calculate confidence intervals they calculated confidence intervals for each rate using 1000 bootstrap and reported only the P-value for the rate difference.

Here are the results reported in the article:

```
Adjusted incidence of disease in the exposed group per 1000: 2.56 (95% CI: 0.96 to 4.33)
Adjusted incidence of disease in the un-exposed group per 1000: 1.19 (95% CI: 0.18 to 2.44).
Risk difference: 1.37 (P: 0.2)
```

However when I use the original data and calculate the disease rates and risk differences using Chi-square I get the following results:

```
Adjusted incidence of disease in the exposed group per 1000: 2.56 (95% CI: 2.13 to 2.99)
Adjusted incidence of disease in the un-exposed group per 1000: 1.19 (95% CI: 0.92 to 1.46).
Risk difference: 1.37 (95% CI: 0.86 to 1.88, P < 0.001)
```

Not to mention the rate ratio of 2.15 (95% CI 1.62 to 2.84)

I apologize for not providing much detail about the study. The reason for that is that I do not want to risk being misinterpreted or harming anyone with wrong judgments about which I do not feel confident given my several limitations in statistics.

However I can provide the following information. The exposure was expected to protect from disease rather than to be associated with increased disease incidence. The study was partly funded by industry and given problems concerning the adjustment for confounding factors, it is likely that the results reflect unmeasured confounding.

My understanding of bootstrap methods is that they are most useful for comparing means of skewed data and I do not understand the choice to use that method in that study if the confidence intervals from Chi-square were much smaller. Is this a genuine methodological option or should this be seen as means to avoid dealing with an inconvenient result?

This question is important for me because I have to make a judgment about the risk of bias in that study concerning the possibility of selective outcome reporting and I do not want to be unfair with the authors by making a wrong judgment about the way they reported their analyses, specially because they reported the data that allowed me to recalculate their results.

Comment: The bootstrap is a general nonparametric technique that can be applied to a variety of statistics.  It may be useful in this application. There is a lot of literature on this as well as many books and posts here.

Comment: @Michael is correct.  However, since the $\chi^2$ test is perfectly applicable and highly significant ($\chi^2=29.27,\ p=6.3\times 10^{-8}$ with continuity correction), and the bootstrap produces a p-value of only $0.2$, something is amiss.  Perhaps there are other covariates?  What is the probability model?

Comment: Many thanks for your answers. Now answering to wuber, According to the report of the study the authors have calculated a weighed measure of the outcome of interest concerning the occurrence of a specific disease. That outcome measure was calculated for both treatment and control groups accounting for sampling days, number of eligible patients, and the probability of being assessed at one of the sentinel sites that assessed patients. The numbers of weighed events in the exposed group and in the non-exposed group were 135 and 77, respectively. Then, they used those proportions in the bootstrap

Comment: Another matter that puzzles me is that in that study they reported to have collected primary data on each participant concerning co-existing diseases, and other important co-variates, but they did not report any statistical analysis adjusting for those co-variates. They only reported the proportions of weighed events over the total population. I really can't understand why one would choose to use bootstrap when a simple Chi-square was very significant and why one would not adjust for important co-variates one already had collected.